# multi-level inheritance in Perl

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I have a question related to multi-level inheritance in Perl.

Here is my code

**mod.pm**

```
package first;

sub disp {
    print "INSIDE  FIRST\n";
}

package second;
@ISA = qw(first);

sub disp {
    print "INSIDE SECOND\n";
}

package third;
@ISA = qw(second);

sub new {
    $class = shift;
    $ref   = {};
    bless $ref, $class;
    return $ref;
}

sub show {
    $self = shift;
    print "INSIDE THIRD\n";
}

1;
```

**prog.pl**

```
use mod;

$obj = third->new();
$obj->show();
$obj->disp();
```

I have a .pm file which contains three classes. I want to access the `disp` method in the first class using an object of third class. I'm not sure how that could work.

I tried to access using two ways:

1. using class name => first::disp()
2. using SUPER inside second package disp method => $self->SUPER::disp();

But am not sure how it will be accessed directly using the object of third class.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do that, then you have defined your classes wrongly.

The `third` class inherits from the `second` class. `second` has it's own definition of `disp`, so it never tries to inherit that method from its superclass `first`. That means `third` gets the implementation defined in `second`

The simple answer would be to call `first::disp` something else. That way `second` won't have a definition of the method and inheritance will be invoked again

If you explain the underlying problem, and why you want to ignore an inherited method, then perhaps we can help you find a better way

Please also note that packages and module files should start with a capital letter, and each class is ordinarily in a file of its own, so you would usually use `package First` in `First.pm` etc.

Comment: Just am trying to find a way using which I can  access the disp method in first package using the object of third package.

Comment: @s.patra: I realise that, but can you explain *why*. Are these packages something that you've written, or have you got them from other places? It would help if I could see the real code.

Comment: I want to implement this concept in my framework which won't be possible to post here. So I just wrote a sample piece of code to verify how it works.

Comment: @s.patra: Okay, so why do you want to implement this in your framework? Your code is saying that `third` is a subclass of `second`, but it's not. You're pulling bits out of `second` and bits out of `first`. It will work fine if you just make `third` a subclass of `first`.

Comment: Yes in that way it will work fine. But I am curious to know if there is any way in which I can access the attribute from grand parent class in grand child class with the object of grand child, first and third in this case.It will be great if you give a sample code  also.

Comment: s.patra: Just set `our @ISA = ('first')` inside `package third` instead of setting it to `('second')`

Comment: that way I am aware . But can it be accessed without doing, in some other way. Or this is the only way.

Comment: @s.patra, Why do you keep asking that when it's been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40793111/589924)?

Comment: Am just asking if there is some other way of doing this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @s.patra: You've been given two ways to do this and you still want more. You must explain the situation thoroughly and why you think this approach necessary as we're just going in circles here. Otherwise, the answer is just that you can't do that, and we leave it there.

Comment: Thanks for your support @borodin.

Answer (score 5):

`$obj->first::disp()`, but what you are asking to do is something you absolutely shouldn't do. Fix your design.